# Fieldset in IE ,Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

This code is working fine in IE and Chrome, except firefox..i have scratching my hair to adjust the fieldset in IE and chrome, but at the end i found out the "TRY ME" has run out 
of the position which was very different in IE and Chrome.. any solution for this?

### css

```
fieldset 
{
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
width:490px;
border: 5px solid Black;
}
```

### html

```
<fieldset>
<legend>
    <h2>
     TRY ME
    </h2>
</legend>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use a `<h2>` inside a `<legend>`? "SEO" reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`legend` elements are notoriously bad to style cross browser.

My best recommendation is to use the `h2` outside of `legend`, and perhaps use `legend` as well, but hide it from view (`text-indent: -9999px`) (screen readers should still  be able to access its semantic goodness).

Comment: I just have to remove the h2 ,everytime will work fines, thx alex and thirtydot